# Load specific SVG based on variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

In my JS file I have a variable called `questionNumber`:

```
var questionNumber = 0;
```

I have all SVGs loaded in my HTML like this:

```
<symbol id="progress-1" viewBow="0 0 134.5 188">    
    <title>progress-1</title>
    <desc>Icon showing progress</desc>
    <path class="a" d="M72.5 18v-4.5c0-3.31 3.19-5.5 6.5-5.5h20.5c3.31 0 6 2.19 6 5.5V18h8V6a6 6 0 0 0-6-6h-37a6 6 0 0 0-6 6v12h8z"/>
    <rect class="a" x="6436.12" y="754.67" width="35.33" height="12.67" rx="6.33" ry="6.33" transform="rotate(-45 2351.07 8168.345)"/><path class="a" d="M124.5 17H50.65c-5.5 0-13.19 3.17-17.09 7.05l-24 23.78c-3.9 3.88-7.09 11.55-7.09 17.05V178a10 10 0 0 0 10 10h112a10 10 0 0 0 10-10V27a10 10 0 0 0-9.97-10zm-1 150c0 4.7-3.75 9-8.33 9H21.84c-4.58 0-8.33-4.34-8.33-9V70.38a23.62 23.62 0 0 1 5.91-14.43l20-20.18C42.67 32.46 49.08 30 53.66 30h61.54a8 8 0 0 1 8.33 8v128.96z"/><path class="a" d="M55.21 36a20.09 20.09 0 0 0-12.69 5.38L24.71 59.93a21.77 21.77 0 0 0-5.2 13.2v88.3c0 4.29 3.19 8.57 7.28 8.57h83.43c4.1 0 7.28-4.27 7.28-8.57V43.57a7.31 7.31 0 0 0-7.28-7.57h-55zm6.22-3.64a9.44 9.44 0 0 1 .07 1.12v-1.24z"/>
</symbol>
```

How do I now call the correct SVG ID based on the variable `questionNumber`? So, if `questionNumber` is `1` then the SVG with id `progress-1` should be called. If `questionNumber` is 2, then SVG with id `progress-2` should be called and so on. Basically something like this (but this is static):

```
<span>
    <svg class="button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 70">
        <use xlink:href="#progress-1"/>
    </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Generate the elements and attributes dynamically with javascript.

Comment: I have no knowledge of SVG in HTML, but would something like `<use id="changeme" xlink:href="#progress-1">` in the HTML, then `document.getElementById("changeme").setAttribute("xlink:href", "#progress=" + questionNumber);` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the string "#progress-" with the return value from `questionNumber`:

```
var questionNumber = 0;
var svgIconToLoad = "#progress-" + questionNumber;
```

Since "progress-" is of type `String` it will convert the value of `questionNumber` (which is `Number`) also to `String`.

For the rest there are many options, you could do something like this:

```
var spanElem = '<span>
                  <svg class="button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 70">
                    <use xlink:href="' + svgIconToLoad + '"/>
                  </svg>
                </span>';
```

And then put it somewhere in your document, let's say you have already selected some element, let it be a `div` with the `id` "svg":

```
var element = document.getElementById("svg");
element.html = spanElem;
```

Comment: @Jepix You're welcome. There was also a typo, I have just changed "progress-" to "#progress-" for the sake of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes, initially with {display:none;} and use javascript or jQuery to alter this to {display:block;} on user input. { visibility : none } leaves enough empty space to show the element, so following elements don't move rightwards or downwards.